# IndexOutOfBoundsException when writing string include ampersand character

Tags: spring-batch

Currently, I using StaxEventItemWriter from SpringBatch 4.2.4 to writing the object to an XML file, In a normal case it working well but in the special case that a string includes the ampersand ('&') character then I got an IndexOutOfBoundsException.

My string is "Bessat J-D & Graf J-M"

Marshaler: org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller (from spring-oxm-5.2.7)

JDK: 11

Here is a log

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: start 12, end 9, length 21
at java.base/java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.checkRange(AbstractStringBuilder.java:1713)
at java.base/java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:213)
at org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.TransactionAwareBufferedWriter.write(TransactionAwareBufferedWriter.java:247)
at java.xml/com.sun.xml.internal.stream.writers.XMLStreamWriterImpl.writeXMLContent(XMLStreamWriterImpl.java:1543)
at java.xml/com.sun.xml.internal.stream.writers.XMLStreamWriterImpl.writeXMLContent(XMLStreamWriterImpl.java:1461)
at java.xml/com.sun.xml.internal.stream.writers.XMLStreamWriterImpl.writeCharacters(XMLStreamWriterImpl.java:701)
at java.xml/com.sun.xml.internal.stream.writers.XMLEventWriterImpl.add(XMLEventWriterImpl.java:175)
at org.springframework.batch.item.xml.stax.NoStartEndDocumentStreamWriter.add(NoStartEndDocumentStreamWriter.java:39)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.output.XMLEventWriterOutput.text(XMLEventWriterOutput.java:105)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.leafElement(XMLSerializer.java:298)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl$StringImplImpl.writeLeafElement(RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java:1040)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl$StringImplImpl.writeLeafElement(RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java:1019)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.TransducedAccessor$CompositeTransducedAccessorImpl.writeLeafElement(TransducedAccessor.java:226)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementLeafProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementLeafProperty.java:100)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:329)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:666)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:128)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:329)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:666)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementNodeProperty.serializeItem(ArrayElementNodeProperty.java:39)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementProperty.serializeListBody(ArrayElementProperty.java:142)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayERProperty.serializeBody(ArrayERProperty.java:129)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:329)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsSoleContent(XMLSerializer.java:563)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:310)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsRoot(XMLSerializer.java:464)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:298)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:158)
at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.marshalStaxResult(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:743)
at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.marshal(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:706)
at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.marshal(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:695)
at org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemWriter.write(StaxEventItemWriter.java:770)
at org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemWriter.write(CompositeItemWriter.java:59)
at org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemWriter$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$fd4a76ae.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:136)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:124)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691)
at org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemWriter$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$199a1a39.write(<generated>)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.writeItems(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:193)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.doWrite(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:159)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.write(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:294)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.process(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:217)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:77)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:407)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:331)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:273)
at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:82)
at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:375)
at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:145)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:258)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:208)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.handleStep(AbstractJob.java:410)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleJob.doExecute(SimpleJob.java:136)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:319)
at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:147)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Thank you

Comment: My problem exactly the same here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/3745. Look like a bug from springbatch

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you happen to figure out a solution for this?

Comment: Hi @broetchen Until now I just have a temporary solution for it by set transactional to false when you are building the StaxEventItemWriter

Comment: Thanks @Phuoc, that seems like a reasonable workaround.